# UTF-8 encoding in VIM

Tags: vim, utf-8

I have no problem with UTF-8 chars in vim while editing, but when I do `set fileencoding=utf-8` and then save and reload the file, vim displays nonascii chars incorrectly.

Why is that happening, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the value of your `'fileencodings'` setting? This setting determines what encodings are tried by Vim to interpret the contents of a buffer that is being loaded. The first encoding that does not result in a conversion error is assumed to be the current file's encoding.

If `utf8` is to be tested you should put it at the beginning of that setting.

Probably you have `fileencodings` set to `latin1` for example. This encoding is always valid (there is no single byte combination that could be rejected).

If you don't want to change `fileencodings` you can reload the file with: `:e! ++enc=utf8`

Comment: @Michael Krelin: +1 and symbol "%" is redundant to re-read the current file, just `:ed ++enc=utf-8` does the same thing

Comment: The solution was: set enc=utf-8